# Cacti - Changing environment variables at runtime.

Tags: perl, environment-variables, cacti

I'm using the Cacti script/command method to collect data. I have a perl script that connects to an Oracle database and returns two numbers. This script works perfectly when run on the command line (Unix).

For this perl script to work properly I have to define several environment variables so that it is able to connect to Oracle.

`$ENV{ORACLE_HOME} = ...etc...`

But - when I create a data input method in Cacti to run this perl script... I recieve an error stating that it is unable to find the DBD/Oracle.pm. (This is because the environment variables are not being set by Perl).

Does anyone know why the ENV variables are set properly when I run this **on command line**?

But they are **not** able to be set when run by Cacti?

*By the way - Cacti is running the perl script as root.*

Comment: Could you tell us where your Oracle.pm is located and show us the script?

Comment: $ORACLE_HOME does not affect perl's ability to find `DBD/Oracle.pm`. If `use DBD::Oracle` reports `Cant' locate DBD/ORacle.pm in ...`, then `@INC` is not set up correctly. Have a look at your settings for the environment variables `$PERL5LIB` and `$PERLLIB` which affect the initial setting of `@INC`.

In general, I've found that once `DBD::Oracle` has been installed, it is not necessary to set `$ORACLE_HOME` in order to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The issue ended up being that Root did not have read access to the Oracle.pm.

Once I stopped looking into the ENV variables being the problem... the permissions were the next obvious issue.

Thanks for your help in the comments.